# С какими глаголами сочетается слово "ударение"?

Tags: орфоэпия

Ударение может ставиться, стоять, падать, находиться, переноситься, сдвигаться, возникать, проявляться, выражаться, реализовываться, обозначаться. Слова могут произноситься с ударением. Все корректно? Есть еще варианты? Желательно в виде сочетаний (ударение ставится, поставить ударение и т. п.)

Answer (score 3):

Ударение **перемещается, сдвигается** с одной морфемы на другую, **выделяет** важное в речи, **помогае**т понять значение слова.

Answer (score 3):

Открыл какой-то учебник об ударениях и посмотрел на первых десяти страницах поиском глаголы, которые употреблялись со словом ударение. Получилось довольно много и не похоже, чтобы они собирались закончиться. Систематизировать лень :)

- встречается
- вызывает (раздражение)
- выражается
- зависит (от чего-то)
- изучается
- имеется
- исчезает
- маркирует
- меняется
- обладает
- образует
- означает
- остаётся
- поддерживается
- привлекает (внимание)
- пропускается
- проясняет
- сохраняется
- указывает
- употребляется

Comment: Спасибо! Я добавил глаголы в мой список и пострался снабдить их примерами. Только насчет "проясняет" у меня сомнения. Единственный пример какой-то странный: ударение проясняет характер интонации тех долгих слогов в литовском... Можете предложить что-нибудь получше?

Comment: @М_Г В данном случае не вижу необходимости искать более авторитетный источник. Более того, если в источнике такого уровня авторитетности мне что-то кажется странным, я стараюсь подкорректировать своё "чувство языка" :)

Comment: @М_Г Похоже, что это слово не из упомянутого учебника Т.Г. Фоминой. Теперь я не могу сказать уверенно, где я его тогда встретил.

Answer (score 1):

Попытка систематизировать ответы.

Ударение:

- возникает (в разных местах)
- встречается
- выделяет (определённый слог)
- вызывает (раздражение)
- выражается (сильно или слабо)
- зависит (от чего-либо)
- изучается
- имеется (Динамическое ударение имеется в русском, английском, чешском и других языках.)
- исчезает
- маркирует (Фразовое ударение маркирует рему высказывания.)
- меняется
- находится (на определённом слоге) - ?
- обладает (признаками, функцией)
- обозначается (каким-либо символом)
- образует (Ударение образует фонетическую целостность слова; ударение образует своего рода вершину; ударение образует резкий контраст «ударность — безударность»)
- остаётся
- падает(на определённый слог)
- перемещается (с одной морфемы на другую)
- переносится (с одной морфемы на другую)
- поддерживается (ударение поддерживается рифмой, ритмом; ударение поддерживается законом аналогии; данное ударение поддерживается как знак причастности к определенной традиции)
- привлекает (внимание)
- пропускается
- проявляется (в речи)
- реализуется (в разных языках по-разному; часто считается, что ударные слоги произносятся с большей силой, чем безударные)
- сдвигается (с одной морфемы на другую)
- сохраняется
- ставится (об ударении как знаке)
- стоит (на определенном слоге)
- указывает
- употребляется

Ударение можно:

- обозначить
- поставить
- расставить (ударения)
- сделать (на чем? на определённом слоге, но на что? на что-либо важное)

Слова, слоги могут:

- находиться под ударением
- произноситься с ударением.